# Passing range object in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This must be a routine n00b problem.  I call myTest Sub from Test Sub but only the call with the argument written out in full works.  When I pass stuff as an argument (ie myTest(stuff)), I get object required error.

Any help to solve my puzzle would be gratefully received

```
Public Sub myTest(Arg1 As Range)
Dim elem As Variant
For Each elem In Arg1
    MsgBox (elem.Value)
Next elem
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
Dim stuff As Range
Set stuff = Worksheets(1).Range("D7:D10")
myTest (Worksheets(1).Range("D7:D10"))
'myTest (stuff)

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is working as is.

Comment: Not if I uncomment myTest (stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from around the input to your function as so:

```
Public Sub myTest(Arg1 As Range)
Dim elem As Variant
For Each elem In Arg1
    MsgBox (elem.Value)
Next elem
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
Dim stuff As Range
Set stuff = Worksheets(1).Range("D7:D10")
myTest stuff

End Sub
```

That should work now.